# anylogic agent communication and message sending

Tags: message, send, anylogic, agent

In my model, I have some agents;

1. "Demand" agent,
2. "EnergyProducer1" agent
3. "EnergyProducer2" agent.

When my hourly energy demands are created in the Main agent with a function, the priority for satisfying  this demand is belongs to "EnergyProducer1" agent. In this agent, I have a function that calculate energy production based on some situtations. The some part of the inside of this function is following;

**" if (statechartA.isStateActive(Operating.busy)) && ( main.heatLoadDemandPerHour >= heatPowerNominal) {
producedHeatPower = heatPowerNominal;

naturalGasConsumptionA = naturalGasConsumptionNominal;

send("boilerWorking",boiler);

} else ..... "**

Here my question is related to 4th line of the code. If my agent1 fails to satisfy the hourly demand, I have to say agent2 that " to satisfy rest of demand". If I send this message to agent2, its statechart will be active and the function of agent2 will be working. My question is that this all situations will be realized at the same hour ??? İf it is not, is accessing variables and parameters of other agent2 more appropiaote way???

I hope I could explain my problem.
thanks for your help in advance...

**Edited question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general comment on your question, within AnyLogic environment sending messages is alway preferable to directly accessing variable and parameters of another agent.

Specifically in the example presented the `send()` function will schedule message delivery the next instance after the completion of the current function.

**Update**: A message in AnyLogic can be any Java class. Sending strings such as "boilerWorking" used in the example is good for general control, however if more information needs to be shared (such as a *double* value) then it is good practice to create a new Java class (let's call is *ModelMessage* and follow [these instructions](https://help.anylogic.com/topic/com.anylogic.help/html/code/adding-java-class.html)) with at least two properties *msgStr* and *msgVal*. With this new class sending a message changes from this:

```java
...
send("boilerWorking", boiler);
...
```

to this:

```java
...
send(new ModelMessage("boilerWorking",42.0), boiler);
...
```

and firing transitions in the statechart has to be changed to use `if expression is true` with expression being `msg.msgString == "boilerWorking"`.

More information about Agent communication is available [here](https://help.anylogic.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.anylogic.help%2Fhtml%2Fagentbased%2Fcommunication.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In fact, I am trying to send a variable value from agent1 to agent2. I mean I have a hourly demand value that firstly meet by agent1 in a function. In this function, I have defined some conditions that are related to ability of agent to satisfy hourly demand value. If agent1 can not meet demand, I want o send a message to agent2 in order to produce the rest of demand value at the same hour.  How can I do it ??

Comment: Ok, i'll edit the answer to include your expanded question.

Comment: this information, really it became very useful for me. I just have a little question.? In msgVal, instead of value (42), can I use such an expression (main.heatLoadDemandPerHour-producedHeatPower) ??

Comment: can you please mark the question as answered?